# Spring Boot v2.5.2 - refresh endpoint is not working

Tags: spring, spring-security, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am using **Spring Boot v2.5.2 Microservices and trying to dynamically refresh the endpoint**. I am using Spring Cloud API Gateway and have implemented security, now when I make the **http://localhost:8012/actuator/busrefresh**, I see only Spring Cloud API gateway has reflected the changes but other microservices doesn't.

How can we fix it?

**Spring Cloud API Gateway**

application.properties

```
server.port=8082
spring.application.name=api-gateway
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka

spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8012

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=users-status-check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/users/status/check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[2]=Header=Authorization, Bearer (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[2]=AuthorizationHeaderFilter

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id = users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/users
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[1]=Method=POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id = users-ws-login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/users/login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[1]=Method=POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].id = users-ws-get-update-delete
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/users/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[1]=Method=GET,PUT,DELETE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[2]=Header=Authorization, Bearer (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].filters[1]=AuthorizationHeaderFilter
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].filters[2]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

#spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
#spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true

#token.secret = hfgry463hf746hf573ydh475fhy5739
token.secret = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest


spring.cloud.gateway.metrics.enabled=true

management.endpoint.gateway.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=gateway,beans,health,routes,httptrace
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApiGateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ApiGateway</name>
    <description>Photo App Eureka Discovery Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

For this microservices, the refreshbus changes works, for user service it doesn't

Users Service

application.properties

```
server.port=0
spring.application.name=users-ws

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}

spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8012


spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

MainApp.java

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class PhotoAppApiUsersApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PhotoAppApiUsersApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>PhotoAppApiUsers</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PhotoAppApiUsers</name>
    <description>Photo App Eureka Discovery Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

source code link - https://github.com/javaHelper/spring-cloud-microservices-latest/tree/master/spring-boot-microservices-spring-cloud-III

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your  location is http://localhost:8012/actuator/busrefresh, this is your spring gateway servere location actuator, however,when you use spring cloud gateway,have  you use agent to anthor server with Unified address, maybe you can try like this "http://localhost:8012/${your server agent location}/actuator/busrefresh", hopefully it's work